# Using STUFF to get children value grouped by parent ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm looking for a solution to get children's values in a single cell, I've found out about `STUFF` but when I'm trying to apply it to a self-referencing table it does not work.

Neither `CONCAT` nor `CONCAT_WS` work '*not a recognized built-in function name*'.

Table:

| ID | ParentID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | HELLO |
| 2 | 1 | Foo |
| 3 | 1 | Bar |
| 4 | 3 | Blob |

My query at this point :

```
SELECT TaskParent.TaskID,
    ValueValues = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ' | ' + TaskChildren.Value
            FROM tblTask TaskChildren
                JOIN tblTask TaskParent2 ON TaskParent.TaskID = TaskChildren.TaskGroupID
            WHERE
                TaskParent2.TaskID = TaskParent.TaskID
                AND TaskParent2.TaskID not like TaskParent2.TaskParentID
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 3, ''
        )
FROM tblTask Task
    JOIN tblTask TaskParent ON TaskParent.TaskID = Task.ParentID
GROUP BY TaskParent.TaskID
```

In the result from the query above I'm getting :

| ParentID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo |

But I want :

| ParentID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo / Bar |

I'm sorry if this was already answered, but I already spent too much time looking for it.

For more details when I add `Task.ID` to the query the result is the following :

| ID | ParentID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | Foo |
| 3 | 1 | Bar |

Here is modifications I made on @@siggemannen solution

```
select TaskParents.ID, substring((select ' | ' + Value from tblTask TaskValues where TaskValues.ParentID = TaskParents.ID for xml path('')), 4, 99999) as Children
from tblTask Task
    LEFT JOIN tblTask TaskParents ON TaskParents.ID = Task.ParentID
group by TaskParents.ID
ORDER BY TaskParents.ID
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Your query is product specific.)

Comment: I'm using MS SQL server 8

Comment: Really? SQL Server version 8 is SQL Server 2000. `stuff` was introduced in SQL Server 2005, so the information you have provided is clearly incorrect.

Comment: Save everyone some time and paste the output of: `select @@version`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3-GDR) (KB4057113) - 10.50.6560.0 (X64)   Dec 28 2017 15:03:48   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Well it's not version *8*, but it is *2008* R2 (version 10.50), which ran *completely* out of support well **over 4 years ago**. If you were using a supported version of SQL Server you could just use `STRING_AGG` rather than `FOR XML PATH` (all `STUFF` is doing is removing the first 3 characters of a string). You really should be implementing that upgrade plan that you (presumably) finalised years ago.

Comment: There is an update planned but I need to achieve the result stated above ASAP, and even without ```STUFF``` the request doesn't do what I need where's when I don't use it on a self-replicating table it does work

Comment: @Stu - `STUFF` is an ancient function that predates SQL Server 2000. It is part of the common code with Sybase. The `FOR XML PATH('')` is probably 2005+ though as XML support in 2000 was limited

Comment: @MartinSmith Ah ok cheers, so LoL I quickly checked with the oracle Chatgpt who informed me *...referring to Microsoft SQL Server, the STUFF function has been available since SQL Server 2005.* - rollseyes.

Comment: STUFF work fine even on sql server 6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```sql
select *
into tblTask
from (
    VALUES  (1, 1, N'HELLO')
    ,   (2, 1, N'Foo')
    ,   (3, 1, N'Bar')
    ,   (4, 3, N'Blob')
) t (ID,ParentID,Value)


select ID, substring((select ' | ' + value from tbltask t2 where t2.parentid = t.id for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 4, 99999) as Children
from tblTask t
group by ID
```

Edit:
Alternative method without TYPE:

```sql
select ID, substring((select ' | ' + value from tbltask t2 where t2.parentid = t.id for xml path('')), 4, 99999) as Children
from tblTask t
group by ID
```

This returns whatever children a parent has:

| ID | Children |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | HELLO | Foo | Bar |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | Blob |
| 4 | NULL |

Comment: Sorry for the bad translation but the query ends with this error :  ```"Task" is not a valid function, property or field.```
I think it comes from the ```.Task('.', 'nvarchar(max)')```

Comment: there's no such code in the answer though?

Comment: Sorry I meant to write "Value" instead of "Task"

Comment: Did you actually write out the code or did you freebase and make your own version. For example, did you skip `, TYPE` part in the for xml?

Comment: I only changed the table names to reflect to the real tables I have, nothing else was changed

Comment: ok, i added another version which you can try

Comment: Your solution worked with perfectly with a bit of tweaking! I'll put your answer as a resolution an put my changes in the question

Comment: I'm curious which sql server are you running, because my code with `.values` worked even on sql server 2005. Oh well, i'm glad you got it working...

Comment: @@version = Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3-GDR) (KB4057113) - 10.50.6560.0 (X64) Dec 28 2017 15:03:48 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)